# How to convert serialise object string into the array in php?

Tags: php

So I have the following string from payment gateway and me wanted to convert it into an array so that It can be stored back to my database easily.

Following is the string:

```
O:22:"Pay\Transaction"
:18:{s:13:"transactionId";
s:13:"402982938-02";
s:15:"merchantSession";
s:18:"PPwmdE91832";
s:17:"merchantReference";
s:40:"a8abd1765283d";........
```

following is the code:

```
$storedTxn = $this->get($txn->transactionId);
    if ($storedTxn) {
        //$new = array();
        foreach ($storedTxn as $key => $value) {
            if (!isset($txn->$key)) {
                $txn->$key = $value;
                //$new[$key] = $value; //this part is not working....
            }

        }

    }
$file = fopen($this->filePath, 'w');
    fwrite($file, serialize($txn));
    fclose($file);
```

So from the above code where I can convert it or store it into array??

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: [`unserialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)?

Comment: no mate its not working

Comment: $new = array(); not "arrat". Have you seen this error?

Comment: I have updated my code but it was just typo mistake while I was uploading my question. It didn't helped me tho

Comment: it dont work because you are using `if (!isset($txn->$key)) {` to fullfill the `$txn`, if you want to just convert `$storedTxn` to array just put the `$new[$key] = $value;` outside of if

Comment: I tried but now the problem is how to write an array into the file like I have below code but its not writing anything into the file except single last character $myfile = fopen($this->myfilePath, 'w');
  //fwrite($myfile,$new);
  //fclose($myfile); However, no issue with the file path or writing permison

Comment: well if you want to write something to file it has to be string, array is not a string, serialize and unserialize should work fine even with the object, you dont need to convert it to array, seems like you dont understand how serialize/unserialize works, write serialized string to the file and after you read it unserialize readed string to an object, btw the object type has to be known at the time you are unserializing the `Pay\Transaction`

Comment: I tried the below code too. However, its not writing the whole string and only return me with 1 character. $string_data = serialize($new);
  file_put_contents($this->myfilePath, $string_data);